# Angular 2: How to share variables from service to multiple components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have one service, and I created a variable named value. When the user clicks the button, its supposed to update the index and change the data in the view. For some reason, the value variable  from the service doesn't update the view in the other templates, but it does in the console. Thanks for your help.

**data service**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

value: number;

constructor() { 
this.value = 0;  // initialized at zero
}

Data(): Promise<Assignment[]> {
 return Promise.resolve(Assignments);
}

}
```

Here is the button component, I want to use the service to make value equal to index to change the data in the view.

**buttoncomponent.html**

```
<button (click)="goTo(Index)"></button>
```

**ButtonComponent.ts**

```
export class ButtonsComponent implements OnInit{

@Input() symbol:number;
@Input() show:boolean;
@Input() left: number;
@Input() buttonPos:number;
@Input() Index:number;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 
}


ngOnInit(): void {

}

// change index on click
goTo(index){
  this.dataService.value = index;
}

}
```

**Testing template for view**
I was trying to test this out to see if the data would change, but its stuck at 0.

```
<div id="titleArea" *ngIf="dataService.value==Index">
  <h1 class="sub"> {{ name }} </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Where/How do you set `Index`?

Comment: @Sasxa I set it in the app component template like this `<div class="Main" *ngFor="let assignment of assignments; let i=index;">
 <app-title [symbol]="assignment.symbol" [name]="assignment.a_title" [Index]="i"></app-title>
</div>`

Comment: Are you registering your provider in the right place? see this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#should-i-add-other-providers-to-a-module-or-a-component-